# Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found. While using docker-compose up command

Tags: docker, angular6

## My angular6 project required file versions.

```
Angular CLI: 6.1.4

Node: 8.11.3

OS: linux x64

Angular: 6

Package                      Version

------------------------------------------------------

@angular-devkit/architect    0.7.4

@angular-devkit/core         0.7.4

@angular-devkit/schematics   0.7.4

@schematics/angular          0.7.4

@schematics/update           0.7.4

rxjs                         6.2.2

typescript                   2.9.2
```

## Dockerfile

FROM node:8

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app

WORKDIR  /usr/src/app

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200

## docker-compose.yml file

version : '3'

services :

angular-service:

```
  container_name : angular-service-container

  build : ./angular5

  volumes : 

   - '.angular5:/usr/src/app'

  ports : 

   - '4200:4200'
```

1) after giving 'docker-compose build' in terminal I got this following output.

Successfully built 29782d001feb.

Successfully tagged angular5_frontend_angular-service:latest

2) After giving 'docker-compose up' in terminal I got this following output.

Recreating angular-service-container ... done

**Attaching to angular-service-container
angular-service-container | Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
angular-service-container | Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
.....................................................................................................................................................
angular-service-container exited with code 1**

**I am not able to resolve this issue " Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found. "**. Please help regarding this.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you probably didnt create your angular project with the v6 cli, so you will have a .angular-cli file instead of an angular.json file

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You could help people answer your question by e.g. providing some context of what you are trying to achive. If you improve the formatting of your question, the Stackoverflow website form will even warn you that your Question is almost 100% code/console output and is lacking explanation.

Comment: Before creating project structure I gave npm install -g @angular/cli. This command gave angular cli version 6.1.4. What I have to do now ?

Comment: Any updates on this ?

Comment: I used cli version 6.1.0 This resolved my issue..